# Strip comments from Julia code to produce a minified file

Tags: string, julia

I have a Julia code that I want to put in somewhere else. The problem is that I need to remove all comments/unnecessary stuff from the code. How can I do this in Julia?

Example:

```
"""
    example(hello::String, world::Int)::Nothing

Prints something.
"""
function example(hello::String, world::Int)::Nothing
    # Hey!
    println("$hello = $world"); # Print something
end
```

I want to open this file in Julia and remove all comments and save this new file:

```
function example(hello::String, world::Int)::Nothing
    println("$hello = $world");
end
```

Or at least this (keeping inline comments is ok for me, as it would be hard to catch cases like `print("#")`):

```
function example(hello::String, world::Int)::Nothing
    println("$hello = $world"); # Print something
end
```

For one-line comments, I can split the code by lines, and filter the lines that `startswith` `#` after `strip()`. But I have no idea about multi line comments.

Comment: You may want to take a look at some Julia packages that can understand code to a great extent, such as `JuliaFormatter` and `JET.jl`. They implement an understanding of the code at the syntax level, and you could probably look to them to see how to remove certain nodes from the syntax tree (in this case, comments, extraneous newlines and spaces, etc) before recomposing it into a file.

Comment: @BallpointBen Thanks, it will be very helpful and, as a bonus, will give me a more deep understanding of ASTs and Julia parsing!